# Set up a mailing list with NNTP access

Tags: mailing-lists

I'd like to communicate with some friends via email. Currently, I just have a group in my Thunderbird address book and I just send emails to the whole list.

It is cumbersome for them to answer to everybody, so I'd like to set up a mailing list like Debian uses.

I do have a simple PHP/MySQL Webserver, but that is about it. A friend of mine has a complete Ubuntu Server that I could use.

What software could I use to get a mailing list with a web interface for subscription and an NNTP access so that I can read through the mails using KNode?

Answer (score 1):

One can use Mailman to setup the mailing lists. This provides an interface via the Web (HTTP) and also via Email. At the time we did not look into NNTP access and just used the email access.

Alternatively one can just create a Google Group, that can also serve as a mailing list.

Comment: but there are salient reasons to insist on NNTP. Very few solutions are out there. FUDforum does web & nntp, but not email. email + nntp is hard to come by for free.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=65152

claims to do the trick. I have not tested it, though.

It is an addon for  vbulletin.org , advertised as:

**NNTP Gateway for Usenet–Newsgroups , Mailing Lists**

or maybe use https://sourceforge.net/projects/webkosa/